# Lotus Notes -- Jquery File in Header

Tags: jquery, lotus-notes

I Included the jQuery files as file resource in my notes database

Problem: I cant figure out how do I refer to these files in my form in which I am trying to use jquery in.

I tried this in the HTMLHeader:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/jquery-min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='/" + @WebDbName + "/jquery-min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put the formula in a hidden, computed for display field named `$$HTMLHead`; notice the two dollar signs.

Formula in the field should be

```
"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/" + @WebDbName+ "/jquery-min.js\"></script>"
```

Edit:

It also works in $$ChangePasswordForm in domcfg.nsf. I used HTML Head Content property. Did you check the filename (dots and dashes)?

[image: Change web password form in Lotus Domino]

Comment: This did not help. There is no difference using the field you mentioned or adding it to the HTMLHeader.

Comment: What is HTMLHeader? There is only "HTML Head Content" form property and the predefined field with built-in functionality that must be named `$$HTMLHead`. If you put the formula in the "HTML Head Content" property or this field, it will be added to form's `head` tag in the generated HTML. If you put something in both, the field's content will be output first, then the form property. What do you see in HTML source when you open the form in browser?

Comment: It is complicated issue. I am working with the Change Password Form. I am finding out that the code for that is internal or something. I am actually waiting for IBM. Thanks for the help.