# How to generate a <script> without the 'type' attribute

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got some  code that needs to NOT have the type attribute in it.  So that instead of it getting converted to

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ...</script>
```

... it should just read

```
<script> ... </script>
```

I don't see an option to not include it in the resource script property.  Even if "type" is left blank, the subsequent html gets created with it.

thanks!
Clem

Comment: Maybe it's obvious in the context lotus-notes, I know nothing about it. But why do you need that removed? Maybe there is a different solution entirely that will work for you.

Comment: maybe the <xp:text id="cf1" tagName="script" escape="false" value="your script"/></xp:text> may help

Comment: Hi René, this is for Google adwords and it requires script to not have that tag.

Comment: Hi  umeli... That worked except that it put the script in the body section and this script needs to be in the head section.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XPages and you can put your code in a separate file, then this code will be rendered without the type attribute and inside the `<head>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:this.resources>

 <xp:headTag tagName="script">
  <xp:this.attributes>
   <xp:parameter name="src" value="/path/to/file.js" />
  </xp:this.attributes>
 </xp:headTag>

 </xp:this.resources>

    Lorem ipsum

</xp:view>
```

Renders like `<script src="/path/to/file.js"></script>`

If you don't have to use XPages, look at my answer [Lotus Notes — Jquery File in Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103376/lotus-notes-jquery-file-in-header/53108534#53108534).

Comment: Hi Roman.... Nice solution!  I will give this a try to see how it works.  Thanks.  I came back here to post a solution which a friend mentioned to me yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Roman, you use the headTag attribute.

```
    <xp:headTag tagName="script">
        <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter name="async src"
                value="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xyz"
                loaded="true">
            </xp:parameter>
        </xp:this.attributes>
    </xp:headTag>
```

This then shows up in the head tag like this:

```
   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xyz"></script>
```

Clem